# return all the row values for a given id

Tags: php, mysql, rows

How do I return all the row values for a given id?

```
require('dbc.php');

mysql_select_db($db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM about WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['content']; // return all values instead of just content
```

Comment: You have all values in your array $row[].

Comment: And please escape ur $_GET['id'] before making database request

Comment: And use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result) ) {

    foreach($row as $column => $value){
        echo "Row: $column - $value<br />";
    }
}
```

But, I would suggest you move to MySQLi, for security and performance purposes. Once you do, you can use:

```
$all_rows = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

You could loop through this or call `implode` on it to return the values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mysql_fetch_row` and then `implode` the array:

```
echo implode(",",mysql_fetch_row($result));
```